# solve err in before insert trigger on pl/sql

Tags: plsql, triggers, oracle-apex, apex, apex-code

I create table b

```
create table b(
id number(3),
name varchar2(5),
birth_day date
);
```

& I create trigger p

```
create or replace trigger p
 before insert on b
 for each row 
 declare
 g number;
 begin
 SELECT MONTHS_BETWEEN(TO_DATE(to_char (sysdate,'DD-MM-YYYY')), TO_DATE (to_char(:new.BIRTH_day,'DD-MM-YYYY')))/12 
   INTO g FROM DUAL;
     IF (g< 18) THEN
      RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20000,'VV');
 
    END IF; 
      IF (g> 18) THEN
      RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20000,'ll');
      end if;
    end;
```

When entering data in the b table birth_day row '08/09/2001'
It is executed  p trigger **but** When entering data in the b table birth_day row '08/09/2000'
It does not run p trigger &
This error is shown: **'error ORA-01841: (full) year must be between -4713 and +9999, and not be 0'**
So that I can when I type '08/09/2000' p trigger is executed
what should I do?

I want when type 08/09/2000 p trigger is execute

Answer (score 1):

Too many *manoeuvres* with dates; why? Dates should be handled as dates, don't make things complicated. 08/09/2001 is a string; use date literal (as my example shows) or `to_date` function with appropriate format model.

```
SQL> create or replace trigger p
  2   before insert on b
  3     for each row
  4  declare
  5    g number;
  6  begin
  7     g := months_between(trunc(sysdate), :new.birth_day) / 12;
  8
  9    IF (g< 18) THEN
 10        RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20000,'VV');
 11    END IF;
 12
 13    IF (g> 18) THEN
 14        RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20000,'ll');
 15    end if;
 16  end;
 17  /

Trigger created.
```

Testing:

```
SQL> insert into b (id, name, birth_day) values
  2    (1, 'Mike', date '1970-02-03');
insert into b (id, name, birth_day) values
            *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-20000: ll
ORA-06512: at "SCOTT.P", line 11
ORA-04088: error during execution of trigger 'SCOTT.P'


SQL> insert into b (id, name, birth_day) values
  2    (1, 'Mike', date '2022-02-03');
insert into b (id, name, birth_day) values
            *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-20000: VV
ORA-06512: at "SCOTT.P", line 7
ORA-04088: error during execution of trigger 'SCOTT.P'


SQL> insert into b (id, name, birth_day) values
  2    (1, 'Mike', date '2005-03-11');

1 row created.

SQL>
```

---

Testing your date value; when you said 08/09/2001, it is unclear whether it is 8th of September (dd/mm/yyyy) or 9th of August (mm/dd/yyyy) so - here you are, both options. Result is `VV` in both cases.

```
SQL> insert into b (id, name, birth_day) values
  2    (1, 'Mike', date '2020-09-08');
insert into b (id, name, birth_day) values
            *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-20000: VV
ORA-06512: at "SCOTT.P", line 7
ORA-04088: error during execution of trigger 'SCOTT.P'


SQL> insert into b (id, name, birth_day) values
  2    (1, 'Mike', date '2020-08-09');
insert into b (id, name, birth_day) values
            *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-20000: VV
ORA-06512: at "SCOTT.P", line 7
ORA-04088: error during execution of trigger 'SCOTT.P'
```

---

No problem with year 2000 either (but outcome is now different because of number of years):

```
SQL> insert into b (id, name, birth_day) values
  2    (1, 'Mike', date '2000-08-09');
insert into b (id, name, birth_day) values
            *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-20000: ll
ORA-06512: at "SCOTT.P", line 11
ORA-04088: error during execution of trigger 'SCOTT.P'


SQL>
```

Once again: value you try to insert, literally `'08/09/2000'` is a **string**; it is enclosed into single quotes. You rely on Oracle's capabilities to implicitly convert that string into a valid `DATE` datatype value. Why `DATE`? Because you created table that way:

```
create table b(
id          number(3),
name        varchar2(5),
birth_day   date              --> this; column's datatype is DATE
);
```

Therefore, you should insert appropriate datatype value into that column - a `DATE`.

You can use

- date literal, which consists of `date` keyword followed by value enclosed into single quotes in format `yyyy-mm-dd`

  - example: `date '2023-03-11'` is today's date, 11th of March 2023
- `to_date` function whose format model follows value you pass

  - example: `to_date('11.03.2023', 'dd.mm.yyyy')`

You should **not** try to insert a string in any format. Oracle might, or might not be able to recognize it. If it doesn't, it'll return error. If it succeeds, code on your computer might work, but porting that application to another database whose NLS settings are different from the ones on your previous server will end up with an error. Now imagine bunch of code which relies in implicit conversion ... you'll be VERY SORRY you thought that passing strings to `DATE` datatype columns was a good idea. It was not, it is not, and it will not be, ever.

Comment: In this trigger that you wrote we can not '08/09/2000' in birth_day row & Unfortunately this err is shown: 'error ORA-01841: (full) year must be between -4713 and +9999, and not be 0'

Comment: Too bad you didn't read everything I wrote. I told you not to insert **string** into a column which accepts **date** datatype. What can I say? Sooner you start paying attention to *small things*, sooner you'll succeed in what you're trying to do.

Comment: Please test with the trigger date '08/09/2020 you wrote and tell me your test answer

Comment: Done; have a look at edited answer, please.

Comment: I'm very sorry ' 08/09/2020' is typo ( mistake type ) ; Can you please date '08/09/2000' in trigger p on table b

Comment: No problem either. I tried to explain it once again. Do read what I said (in edited answer) and try to understand what I'm saying. It is not trigger that doesn't work, but you, trying to insert invalid value into DATE datatype column.